# Kahler form lies in $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

$X$ is a Kahler manifold. Then is it true that the class of Kahler form $[\omega]$ lies in $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$?

In fact I am not sure I understand $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ correctly. Why can we talk about $H^2_{dR}(X,\mathbb Z)$? Because I don't think "forms with integer coefficients" is well-defined.

---

**Edit**

I didn't make question clear. As Tsemo Aristide's answer suggests, if $\omega$ is a kahler form, then so is $c \omega$. So I really want to ask is: can we always find a $c$ such that $c\omega$ lies in $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: TypIcally these types of questions really mean: 1. Show that $\omega$ is closed and 2 Show that $[\omega] \neq 0$. The Kahler form is closed (it is symplectic), and if you look at the class of the top wedge power of $\omega$ this must be nonzero. Thus $[\omega] \neq 0$.

Comment: @Rellek But does it lie in $H^n(X,\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: No, it is a $2$-form. Elements of $H^n (X , \mathbb{Z})$ are classes of $n$-forms (assuming $n \neq 2$).

Comment: @Rellek Yes but I mean $n=2$.

Comment: Not in general. When it does it is sometimes called a Hodge Manifold. It is an important special case because of the Kodaira embedding theorem.

Comment: @Jake Thanks! One more question: I saw two "Kodaira embedding theorem". One is as you stated and another is with the condition that there exists a positive line bundle. Are they the same?

Comment: @UserX Yes. One way to get an idea of how they are related is to consider the exponential sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to {\mathcal{O}_X}\mathop  \to \limits^{\exp } {\mathcal{O}_X}^ \times  \to 0$. Taking the LES of sheaf cohomology, and using the identification ${H^1}\left( {X,{\mathcal{O}_X}^ \times } \right) \cong Pic\left( X \right)$, we get a map $Pic\left( X \right)\mathop  \to \limits^{{c_1}} {H^2}\left( {X,\mathbb{Z}} \right)$. The image of that positive line bundle under this map should be the same as the cohomology class of the Kahler form.

Comment: @Jake Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my late reply ,there is a more general theorem to describe this fact,by Huybrechts'Complex Geometry 5.3 Kodaira Embedding theorem Corollary 5.3.3,we have

A compact Kähler manifold $X$ is projective if and only if $\mathcal K_X\cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\not=\emptyset .$

Here $\mathcal K_X$ denotes the Kähler cone,so we can find counterexample from non-projective manifolds,such as some complex torus,neither Kähler class associated to any Kähler structure lies in $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the $2$-torus endowed with its standard Kahler form $\omega $. Let $i$ be any irrational number $i\omega$ is also a Kahler for the same complex structure but is not in $H^2(\mathbb{T}^2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  But can we find a $c$ such that $c \omega$ lies in $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$? (I edited the question)